# Dynamic column name in panda dataframe evaluation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm referencing a dataframe as follows (`Sales` is the column name):

```
total = pd.to_numeric(sales_df.Sales.str.replace("$", "")).sum()
```

But I don't want `Sales` to be hard coded, I want a variable to make it dynamic. How is this done?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can should index your columns by using square brackets:

```
df['col_name']
```

So when you accept the input as a `str` you can just do:

```
total = pd.to_numeric(sales_df[user_input_name].str.replace("$", "")).sum()
```

Additionally accessing columns as an attribute can lead to ambiguous behaviour. Such as having a column named `index` and you try to do `df.index` which may have different values to the column `df['index']` or if you had a column named the same as any valid df method like `sum` or `var` then this will lead to syntax errors.

So I strongly advise you use square brackets to select columns.