# Fill DataFrame using dynamic Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im working on a student project for machine learning, using python and pandas for analyzing webdata. Therefore I need to convert multiple lines of data (from one session) in one line. The session has a variable length, each row consist of 5 values : referer, ip, time, requestAdress, session, which i want to get stored into columns.

```
    df_row = pd.DataFrame()
    length_session = len(df_work[df_work['session'] == session])
    for row in df_work[df_work.session == session].itertuples():                                                      #tuple = referer, ip, time, requestAdress, session
        for i in range(1,len(row)):
            name = ['referer', 'ip', 'time', 'requestAdress', 'session']
            df_row[str(name[i-1]) + str(length_session)] = row[i]
            print row[i]
        length_row-=1
    print(df_row)
```

The Output is:

```
https://www.google.de/
x5d80e060.dyn.telefonica.de
2016-07-06 03:41:02
/kuenstlerbedarf/oelfarben/
-8730846718325754703

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [referer28, ip28, time28, requestAdress28, session28, referer27, ip27, time27, requestAdress27, session27, referer26, ip26, time26, requestAdress26, session26, referer25, ip25, time25, requestAdress25, session25, referer24, ip24, time24, requestAdress24, session24, referer23, ip23, time23, requestAdress23, session23, referer22, ip22, time22, requestAdress22, session22, referer21, ip21, time21, requestAdress21, session21, referer20, ip20, time20, requestAdress20, session20, referer19, ip19, time19, requestAdress19, session19, referer18, ip18, time18, requestAdress18, session18, referer17, ip17, time17, requestAdress17, session17, referer16, ip16, time16, requestAdress16, session16, referer15, ip15, time15, requestAdress15, session15, referer14, ip14, time14, requestAdress14, session14, referer13, ip13, time13, requestAdress13, session13, referer12, ip12, time12, requestAdress12, session12, referer11, ip11, time11, requestAdress11, session11, referer10, ip10, time10, requestAdress10, session10, referer9, ip9, time9, requestAdress9, session9, ...]
Index: []
```

So, the dynamic naming of the columns work, but the DataFrame remains empty. All I found according this problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565417/dynamically-adding-columns-to-pandas-dataframe) and [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970349/dynamic-column-name-in-panda-dataframe-evaluation).

I want to know why the assignment at: `df_row[str(name[i-1]) + str(length_row)] = row[i]` does not work, and how i can achieve my goal to fill the dynamically named columns with the given values.

A big THANX in advance!

Comment: If your df is initially empty then simply assigning like this won't add a row, you need to use `append`

Comment: what's `df_row`, all i can see is `row`

Comment: sry. edited code snippet.

Comment: ah ok, then edchum's comment is the right one... what you are doing there is changing the existing values of the dataframe which is empty, so you need to append the row... however, this will be slow... the suggested way would be to allocate a large enough dataframe and then trim it as needed. Also seems you can safely take `name = ['referer', 'ip', 'time', 'requestAdress', 'session']` out of the loops.

Comment: @EdChum +JohnSmith : Thank you, like you said, the empty DataFrame was the Problem. Do you want to post an answer, or is this question going to the trash? :)

Comment: You started with an empty df, assignment using your code does not expand the df bby appending, you need to call `append` also this is very inefficient what you're doing, Can you explain more of what your code is trying to do here, also see this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement which explains why what you tried didn't work you need to use `loc` to enlarge the df

Comment: @JohnSmith As you said, the working function IS slow. So you mean i should build a static DataFrame with lets say 10000 columns instead of building it dynamically? Is that not inefficient? Or is there a way to insert the name-generation of the columns into an apply?

I start with a data format like:

Comment: I start with a data format like:
session - ip -  referer
1 - 2 - 3
1 - 4 - 5
2 - 6 - 7

and i need it as:
session - ip1 - referer1 - ip2 - referer2
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
2 - 6 - 7 - NaN - NaN

where I need the columns named in a senseful way. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: Uhh that looks ugly... sry for that^

Comment: steps to do: 1) start with a large MxN dataframe, 2) populate it as you wish but do not name the columns here, 3) keep the columns you want, 4) rename the columns. if you provide the inputs in python then it would be easier to write smth.

Comment: hmm, ok. Thanks for this beginner-friendly advice! :)